# It is possible to draw rounded RegularPolygon in WPF - Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

I want to do shape like in below image. It is possible to do this with "RegularPolygon" available in MS Blend?

[shape to drew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtK0j.png)

It's my code for now

```
xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" 

 <ed:RegularPolygon x:Name="Hexagon3" Fill="#ED254E" InnerRadius="10" StrokeDashArray ="20" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeDashOffset="10" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,20,0,0" Height="80" Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Hexagon1}" PointCount="6" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <ed:RegularPolygon.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>                        
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ed:RegularPolygon.RenderTransform>
        </ed:RegularPolygon>
```